# Where should I save a SQL table on my computer?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am currently creating a database for my project and was wondering where I should save the table. Should I just save it in documents (`D:\Documents`) or should I save it in the same folder where my project is saved (`D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ALevelCompUnit3`)? I was hoping to develop it at school.

Also, the school only provides Visual Basic 2008; would I have to change the framework to do it at school?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SQL Server Express in fact is a light weight version of the SQL server engine that is stored locally on your file system under the extension .mdf.  Within this file you will be saving things like tables, views and stored procedures.  You can move this file around similar to other traditional file types and where you store it while your developing your application is up to you. If, and when you application grows you may consider moving it over to a full version of SQL Server and there are tools to quickly migrate over.  In regards to your Visual Studio versions - Using 2015 at home and switch over to 2008 at school will be a little painful.  There are many features of 2015 that are not available in 2008.  You should be able to access the .mdf file but your experience will not be as powerful in terms of capabilities.